# No packages Apache and mod_wsgi3 have been found in the repositories

Tags: software-installation, freebsd, apache-httpd

I'm trying to instal [Apache24 and mod_wsgi3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-a-django-site-with-apache-mod_wsgi-and-mysql-on-freebsd-10-1) to my FreeBSD VPS (droplet) with this command:

```
sudo pkg install bash ap24-mod_wsgi3 py27-virtualenv mysql56-server
```

but apparently 'ap24-mod_wsgi3' has been removed from the repositories:

```
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'ap24-mod_wsgi3' have been found in the repositories
```

So, to install Apache24 and mod_wsgi3 I can do it installing them through the ports:

```
# cd /usr/ports/www/apache22
# make install
```

and for mod_wsgi3

```
# cd /usr/ports/www/mod_wsgi3
# make
# make install
```

Should this generate the same results as installing it through 'ap24-mod_wsgi3'?

Answer (score 2):

The port `www/mod_wsgi3` was updated and replaced by the port [`www/mod_wsgi4`](http://www.freshports.org/www/mod_wsgi4/).

So try

```
pkg install www/mod_wsgi4
```

If you're fine with using version 4.

If you still want to work with the port system you should update your ports tree first.
Since you have an old state of it or else the `www/mod_wsgi3` wouldn't be there.

In general it is possible to mix ports and packages, but as far as I know you need protect the packages that were build with ports, by executing

```
pkg lock $PACKAGENAME
```

If you forget that, `pkgng` will replace your custom package with the next upgrade from the repositories.
This might have changed or might change in the future and you should check first if this is still the way to do it, since there is very active development on `pkgng`.